# the if formulae

Tags: excel, excel-formula

creating a excel template for poker. in it i will have say a cell (which represents my hand) that has say 98o which represents a nine and eight off suit.

In another table will show the potential hands that my opponent could have.

there are 6 ways of having a pair of nines and 6 ways of having a pair of eights. But since i am holding an 8 and 9, now there only 4 ways of holding a pair of nines and four ways of holding a pair of eights.

Thus i want a logical formulae that asks

```
=if((there is a 9 in cell a1), 4, 6)
```

cheers

Comment: Actually there's only *3* unordered ways of holding a pair if one is already missing.  Example: if you are holding 9s (nine of spades), then an opponent with a pair of nines could have 9h9d, 9h9c, or 9d9c.  There's no fourth combination of two nines.

Comment: It might help to specify what the data structure of the cell value is.  Below you say that 'a9s' is one possible value as is 'k9o'.  Without knowing much more, you might want to consider having two cells each with the fully specified card ('9h', 'Ks').

Comment: rbarryyoung-my bad its 3 in the morning. MichealT-i am going to put the the fully specified cards but in just one cell, but for the purposes of this question i dont think it matters too much.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple to find if A1 is a 9:

```
=IF(A1 = 9, 4, 6)
```

If you mean you want to see if the value in `A1` *contains* a 9, then you want:

```
=IF(FIND(A1,"9"), 4, 6)
```

Comment: but a1 will not simply equal 9 or 8 or what ever. it might be k9o, which means king and a 9 off suited, or a1 might equal a9s which means ace and a 9 suited. Thus im asking "if there's a 9 in cell a1" and not "if cell a1 equals 9"

Answer (score 0):

i looked about and this seems to work.

=IF(ISERROR(FIND("9", H2))=TRUE, 6, 3)

anyone know of anything simpler

Comment: you don't need `=TRUE`, as it will select the `6` if the `ISERROR` test is true as a function of the IF statement

Answer (score 0):

This formula may help you:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*9*")>0,4,6)
```

Comment: Why not simplify this down to `=IF(COUNTIF(A1,"*9*")>0,4,6)`??